# Why is my DBMS Scheduler Job not executing?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, scheduler, jobs

I am creating a housekeeping job which will delete the data which is older than a week, for that I have written a job which will run periodically.
In sql developer when I see status of job it shows succeeded every time, but in reality the job does the specified work only first time or when i perform any edit in it. can you please help me to identify whats wrong?

my table has a field updated date in format '2018-05-06' so I am using it to identify which records are older

```
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"OWNER"."test"',
            job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
            job_action => 'DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 is
      SELECT updateddate, IDENTIFIER FROM LIMITS;

   my_updateddate VARCHAR2(255 CHAR);
   my_identifier VARCHAR2(255 CHAR);
   templateMessage3 VARCHAR2(255 CHAR);
   templateMessage4 VARCHAR2(255 CHAR);

BEGIN
   FOR i IN c1 LOOP
      my_updateddate:=i.updateddate;
      my_identifier:=i.identifier;
      templateMessage3 := replace(my_updateddate, ''-'', '''');
      templateMessage4 := TO_DATE(templateMessage3, ''yyyymmdd'');
      IF templateMessage4 < sysdate-7 THEN
      Delete from LIMITS where identifier=my_identifier AND updateddate=my_updateddate;
      END IF;
      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-05-29 15:11:19 Asia/Calcutta','YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS TZR'),
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=3',
            end_date => NULL,
            job_class => '"SYS"."DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS"',
            enabled => True,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => 'housekeeping',
            credential_name => NULL,
            destination_name => NULL);

    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"OWNER".""', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);

    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => '"OWNER"."test"');
END; 
/
```

My job shows status succeeded every time but it is deleting rows only first time.
I am expecting it to delete older data every time it runs

Comment: How can it delete the older data the second time on the same day? As you mentioned, `updateddate` field appears to be a string type and it is not storing time component. Also, what is wrong in simply writing `Delete from LIMITS where to_date(updateddate,'yyyy-mm-dd') < sysdate - 7` in place of all those loops and variables?

Comment: I manually inserted  the data to check whether it is deleting that but the data remained as it is, it was not deleting the data after first time.

Comment: Are u committing it after insert?

Comment: you are right Kaushik. I didn't committed the insert statements now i have added the commit statement and it is working fine. Thank you so much. :) :)  and I will also use your suggestion of Delete from LIMITS where to_date(updateddate,'yyyy-mm-dd') < sysdate - 7 .